# Awk - Comparing several columns of each line to the previous line

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I've made several attempts at this but clearly missing something and need help.

I have a large table of thousands of lines of information and I'm trying to classify them into groups based on columns 3, 4 and 6. I've already sorted the lines by these columns and now simply want to do the following:

If column 3=previous lines column 3 && column 4 < previous lines column 5 && column 6 = previous lines column 6; then print the row but ammend the start with the line number of the first occurring match; else print the row but ammend the start with the current line number

This was my awful approach full of faults:

```bash
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } {if ($4<prev5 && $3==prev3 && $6==prev6) print Marker,$0;else Marker=NR print NR,$0; prev5=$5; prev3=$3; prev6=$6}'
```

Example input (comma delimited for simplicity of viewing):

```
a,b,2,15,50,ABBA    
a,a,2,26,55,ABBA    
b,a,2,80,99,ABA    
c,a,3,20,40,CAN    
a,b,3,51,300.CAN    
a,a,4,1000,2000,ART   
d,c,4,1700,2050,ART    
b,a,4,1800,2051,ART
```

Example output:

```
1,a,b,2,15,50,ABBA    
1,a,a,2,26,55,ABBA    
3,b,a,2,80,99,ABA    
4,c,a,3,20,40,CAN    
5,a,b,3,51,300.CAN    
6,a,4,1000,2000,ART   
6,c,4,1700,2050,ART    
6,b,a,4,1800,2051,ART
```

I'm just trying to group these lines by the given criteria, so the group identifier does not need to use the line number method I've suggested, not if theres a better way to do it.

I really hope someone can help with this as I'm always keen to improve on the basic code I know, so also, if possible, please provide explanation as well, as I would like to learn from my mistakes!

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was easier to demonstrate input and output using comma as delimiter, but the actual dataset is TAB delimited. I've adjusted the question accordingly

Comment: Sorry, can you put your technical challenge into more broad terms? Such as "I have two columns of values, HI and LO, and I'm looking for an overlap from row-to-row... ", or some similar mathematical description? The point being if the problem is adequately identified, future U&L users will be able to find it more easily. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it considerably more readable by spreading the code across several lines:

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS }

    # Each line
    {
        if($3 == prev[3] && $4 < prev[5] && $6 == prev[6])
        {
            # Capture and use record number of last match
            if(!nrMatched) { nrMatched = NR-1 }
            print nrMatched, $0
        }
        else
        {
            # No match, reset matched flag and just copy record through
            nrMatched = 0
            print NR, $0
        }

        # Save fields from this line for next comparison
        split($0, prev)
    }
' datafile
```

Output

```
1,a,b,2,15,50,ABBA
1,a,a,2,26,55,ABBA
3,b,a,2,80,99,ABA
4,c,a,3,20,40,CAN
5,a,b,3,51,300.CAN
6,a,a,4,1000,2000,ART
6,d,c,4,1700,2050,ART
6,b,a,4,1800,2051,ART
```